# dijit menu onmouseover

Tags: menu, dojo, onmouseover

I am using menu using  dijit.menu and Its work with right click and left click.
How I open the menu on mouse over and close on onmouseout?

```
dijitActionMenu = new dijit.Menu({
   targetNodeIds:[actionMenuId],
   leftClickToOpen:"true"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
// Create a new Tooltip
var tip = new dijit.Tooltip({
    // Label - the HTML or text to be placed within the Tooltip
    label: '<div class="myTipType">This is the content of my Tooltip!</div>',
    // Delay before showing the Tooltip (in milliseconds)
    showDelay: 250,
    // The nodes to attach the Tooltip to
    // Can be an array of strings or domNodes
    connectId: ["myElement1","myElement2"]
});
```

More details are here [dialogs_tooltips](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dialogs_tooltips/).Even dijit.Menu have onMouseOver even.

[onMouseOver Event](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dijit/Menu/onMouseOver)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the dijit/Menu `onmouseover`.

Create an element which will invoke onmouseover event.

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="show();"  onmouseout="hideMenu();">Element</a>
```

`show()` will call custom widget which will create menu for you.

E.g.,

```js
show = function() {
    var roll = new rollover()
}
```

And rollover.js will be the custom widget.

From the constructor of it, you can invoke the function and create the menu.

```js
pMenu = new Menu({ class: "rollovermenu", id: "rolloverid" });
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a new menu widget each time you mouseover the target? That doesn't seem like a good idea.